# Pik Install Ruby Yields: Error: Private method 'gsub' called for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pik

I just installed pik, and when trying:

```
 pik install ruby 1.9.3-p193
```

I received the error:

```
There was an error.
 Error: private method 'gsub' called for nil:NilClass

in: pik/commands/install_command.rb:24:in 'execute'
in: pik_runner:33
```

Thanks, suggestions?

Comment: is your machine  is 64 bit , then follow this: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/145

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue installing ruby 2.0.0 64bit version.
I had to work around by manually installing Ruby then adding it to pik list.

> pik add c:\Ruby200-x64\bin
>   ** Adding:  200: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]
>    Located at:  C:\Ruby200-x64\bin
>
> pik list
>   * 193: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
>     200: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]